# Trivial dynamic mod_rewrite

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, dynamic

Yes, it's trivial, but can I get the regular expressions to work? Plainly not.

I need to turn

```
http://example.com/search.php?widget_id=X4234-000
```

into

```
http://example.com/show.php?noddy_id=X4234-000
```

I tried,

```
RewriteRule  search\.php\?widget_id=(.+?)$ show.php?noddy_id=%1
```

and also

```
RewriteRule  search\.php\?widget_id=(.+?)$ show.php?noddy_id=$1
```

(hat tip to Dr Fells!)

But no success. Any pointers anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't match the query string with the RewriteRule. For that use the RewriteCond directive :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} widget_id=(.*)$ 
RewriteRule  search\.php show.php?noddy_id=%1 [L]
```

(BTW, %x are for group matches in rewrite conds and $1 in rewrite rules)

Eventually you can add QSA to the flags if you have additional variables in the QueryString you want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

Simple indeed! %1 should be $1

Comment: Thanks for the vote of confidence ;-) But, nope, that don't work either ( I had had that at one point :-(  )

Comment: Are the other rules after this one in the .htaccess that could be overriding it?